# Zend 1 php how to get helper and execute it outside of the class?

Tags: php, zend-framework, helper

I need to be able to execute this code in a php debug tool:

```
 $magicStuff = $this->getHelper('magic')->doMagic();
```

I have a helper, which I need to execute within a PHP debugging tool. For that reason, I need to "call" to this helper to be able to use.

I have tried this but It seems I'm**strong text** missing something along the way. I'm pretty new to Zend, I'll appreciate your help.

magic.php

```
/**
 * Helper declared in the actions/helpers/magic.php file
 */
class Magic_Controller_Helper extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{

    /**
     * Do some magic and return data.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function doMagic()
    {
        return $getStuff;
    }
}
```

I have tried with:

```
$helper = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getHelper('magic');
$results= $helper->doMagic();
var_dump($results);
```

I get back:

```
Action helper "magic" has not been registered with the helper broker
Exception:
Message: Action helper "magic" has not been registered with the helper broker
   Code: 0
```

Comment: From the class names, is this Zend Framework 1? It's worth making that clear, because that [reached end of life 4 years ago](https://framework.zend.com/blog/2016-06-28-zf1-eol.html). If you just say "Zend Framework", people will assume Zend Framework 3, now renamed Laminas MVC, which is a very different framework.

Comment: @IMSoP you are right, I have added it to the question. it is actually Zend 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably missing the registration of your library namespace and actionhelper path.
In your application.ini add the following

```
resources.frontController.actionhelperpaths.Magic_Controller_Action_Helper = "Magic/Controller/Action/Helper"

autoloadernamespaces.Magic = "Magic_"
```

The "Magic" library should exists under "library" folder.
If you do not have your helper under the "Action" namespace try to remove it

```
resources.frontController.actionhelperpaths.Magic_Controller_Helper = "Magic/Controller/Helper"
```